# Recurring mojibake issues in jsp.java files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, encoding, mojibake

A newbie to programming. As part of my on-the-job training, I am doing a project in Struts using Eclipse and Tomcat that involves JSP pages for logging in, searching and displaying database results, and editing certain files in that database. Because I am at a Japanese workplace, all text is of course in Japanese.

Mojibake issues include:

1. mojibake in the jsp.java files produced by Eclipse from the JSP files themselves; the transformation into mojibake leads to syntax errors in certain areas;
2. the JSP pages themselves displaying mojibake in browser when first loaded for the day; however, editing them slightly and resaving them makes this disappear, albeit temporarily. The problem comes back if I ever have to edit a jsp.java file directly, and also whenever it feels like it.
3. All text in pop-up windows from Javascript also was displayed as mojibake; this issue has since resolved itself, but I have no idea how.

It seems like this must be a settings problem; all JSPs (save for a couple of dummy pages that only input a line of text and no input) have been set with charset=UTF-8 and pageEncoding=UTF-8. Java class files, source files, JS files, JSPs, and the workspace have also been set with UTF-8 encoding. The project text file encoding itself has also been set to UTF-8.

Is there anything I'm missing or should be looking more closely at?

Comment: What are "jsp.java files"?

Comment: Sorry if I'm using weird terms - I'm referring to the files in Eclipse's work folder, which are the JSP files converted (compiled?) to .java files. So if I had sample.jsp it would be converted to sample.jsp.java in Eclipse's work folder before being run on the server.

Comment: Your app server translates and compiles the JSP file itself when it executes them for your web browser. If you're seeing incorrect syntax errors reported from within Eclipse, then you should report them as a bug with sample files to recreate them.